# How to Derive Weights and Offsets from Linear SVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

The linear SVM model trained by Matlab is as follows:

Alpha
Beta
Bias
Mu
Sigma
SupportVectors
SupportVectorLabels

May I ask how to use above parameters to calculate the weights and offsets of the hyperplane ?

hyperplane: f(x) = sign((w,x) + b)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Ocaso For what it's worth, the [original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWrZ2.png) of the MATLAB workspace was far more useful than the plaintext edit to try and describe it. I don't think that was an egregious use of code-as-an-image, it would have just been best supported by a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The information that you need are:

```
mdl = fitcsvm(...,...); %This is your model
supportVectors = mdl.SupportVectors; % The support vectors
alpha = mdl.Alpha; % The coefficients
bias = mdl.Bias; % The bias
w = (alpha .* supportVectors)'; % The weights
```

After this, you can use the coefficients like this:

```
x_new = [record you want to test];
decision_function = (w * x_new') + b;
prediction = sign(decision_function); % The prediction
```

FYI, you can also just do:

```
prediction = mdl.Predict(x_new);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!<br>
Obtaining weights and biases is for the convenience of analyzing hyperplanes, therefore, the prediction results were not directly obtained using the functions provided by MATLAB.
I tried your result, but it doesn't seem to be the expected result.<br>
My approach is: <br>w=(Alpha. * SupportVectorLabels) '* SupportVectors/ Sigma<br>
But I cannot calculate the bias.

Comment: check this link for more detail... https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm.html. Technically the bias is already a property of the model, why do you need to calculate it? Also, sigma is only returned in MATLAB when you standardize the predictors. You can also get it manually by using the std() function